# How to compare two branches in CVS with IntelliJ idea

Tags: branch, diff, intellij-idea, cvs

I am trying to compare project branch checked out via IntelliJ idea against another branch of the same project.

I understand that with CVS `diff` I would use (for a single file):

`diff -u -r sourceRevision -r destRevision filename`

This works pretty well from IntelliJ idea as well ... `Right click file` -> `CVS` -> `Compare With`

But my goal is to see the different between whole branches not just a single file. Is there a way to do it?

Using IntelliJ 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IDEA can't diff directories, only files.

Comment: :( And how do you accomplish this? As a general question unrelated to IntelliJ

Comment: I would perform 2 checkouts into different folders, side by side, like trunk and branch, then I'd use some external tool to perform diff/merge. My preferred one is Araxis Merge.